# Optimize Angular 2 application build duration with webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I build an Angular 2 application and bundle it with webpack.
At the moment, my application is still small but the webpack task already takes around 10 seconds.
Is it possible to optimize my webpack config or the TypeSript compilation options to improve the compilation and packaging duration ?

This is the webpack config I use :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/assets/app/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'myApp.bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build/'
  },
  // Turn on sourcemaps
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin({
      appendScriptTag: true
    }),
    // Fixes angular 2 warning
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      __dirname
    )
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": [
      "core-js",
      "systemjs"
    ],
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE** *(see my answer for the fixed webpack.config)*

I give a try to the DLL webpack plugin suggested by @jpwiddy by compiling angular in a separate build, in order to have to rebuild only the application code during developments and gain considerable time of compilation.

However, after an inspection of the output JS, the file size is quite the same and there is still angular code inside.

Here is the new webpack config file for angular sources :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
      angular:[
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/forms'        
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'ng2.dll.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    library: 'ng2'
  },
  plugins: [
    // Fixes angular 2 warning
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      __dirname
    ),
    new webpack.DllPlugin({ 
        name: 'ng2', 
        path: __dirname + '/build/ng2.json'
    })
  ]
}
```

And the updated webpack config for application :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/assets/app/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'myApp.bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build/'
  },
  // Turn on sourcemaps
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin({
      appendScriptTag: true
    }),
    // Fixes angular 2 warning
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      __dirname
    ),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: __dirname + '/build/',
      manifest: require(__dirname + '/build/ng2.json')
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is one of the angular code I found in my application JS output :

```
_TsEmitterVisitor.prototype.visitBuiltintType = function (type, ctx) {
    var typeStr;
    switch (type.name) {
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].Bool:
            typeStr = 'boolean';
            break;
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].Dynamic:
            typeStr = 'any';
            break;
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].Function:
            typeStr = 'Function';
            break;
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].Number:
            typeStr = 'number';
            break;
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].Int:
            typeStr = 'number';
            break;
        case __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__output_ast__["R" /* BuiltinTypeName */].String:
            typeStr = 'string';
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unsupported builtin type " + type.name);
    }
    ctx.print(typeStr);
    return null;
 };
```

Did I missed something in the new config to prevent webpack including angular sources in the output ?

Thank you

Comment: [commons-chunk-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) may also help. Check out configuration of [angular2-webpack-brief-starter](https://github.com/dominik791/angular2-webpack-brief-starter/blob/master/webpack.dev.js) to see how you can use it specifically for all vendor files (including angular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my config with the brand new module [webpack-dll-bundles-plugin](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/webpack-dll-bundles-plugin) (which uses *DllPlugin* and *DllReferencePlugin* in background) doing exactly what I was looking for : isolating the build of Angular 2 in his own bundle, and avoid rebuilding my whole bundle each time I want to rebuild my application code (eg with a watcher).

My re-build time dropped from 10sec to 1sec.

Here is my new webpack config :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/assets/app/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'myApp.bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build/'
  },
  // Turn on sourcemaps
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin({
      appendScriptTag: true
    }),
    // Fixes angular 2 warning
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      __dirname
    ),
    new DllBundlesPlugin({
        bundles: {
          vendor: [
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/router',
            'rxjs',
          ]
        },
        dllDir:  __dirname + '/build/',
        webpackConfig: {}
      })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One great way I've personally done that has sped up the Webpack build process is implementing DLLs within your build.

Webpack works by analyzing your code for `require`s and `import`s, and then builds a table from these statements of all of your module dependencies and links to where those files can be found.

The DLL plugin improves on this, as when you register your dependencies with a DLL, every time those dependencies change (should be very infrequent), you build a DLL (made up of a javascript bundle and a JSON manifest file) and wraps all of those dependencies in a single package. That package is then referenced when pulling in those dependencies into the app.

A quick example:

```
entry: {
    angular:[
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/forms'        
    ],
    bs: [
        'bootstrap', 
        'ng-bootstrap'
    ]
}, 

output: { 
    filename: '[name].dll.js', 
    path: outputPath, 
    library: '[name]', 
}, 

plugins: [ 
    new webpack.DllPlugin({ 
        name: '[name]', 
        path: join(outputPath, '[name].json') 
    })
]
```

... and then referenced as so -

```
{
    plugins: [ 
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: process.cwd(),
            manifest: require(join(outputPath, 'angular.json'))
        }),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: process.cwd(),
            manifest: require(join(outputPath, 'bs.json'))
        }),
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @jpwiddy , thank you for your answer. I gave a try to your DLL solution but didn't have the expected result. Can you please check my config files in my updated post if there is something looking weird to you ? Thank you :)

Comment: @bviale can you mark my answer as correct ans please? :)